# Chrome loading extension when opened vs I reloading manually an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanna clear my history and cache automatically only when I open my browser, but not when I reload the extension from  chrome://extensions. How do I do it? I'm talking about Chrome JavaScript API. I use the latest version of Google Chrome, on Ubuntu 16.04.

LE: I made an extension that among many things clears my history and cache. In manifest.json, I have:

```
"background": {"scripts": ["SessionManager.js"],"persistent":true},
```

In SessionManager.js, I have:

```
function init(){
    setTimeout(clean,1);
}
function clean(){
    chrome.browsingData.remove({},{'appcache':true,'cache':true,'cookies':true,'downloads':true,'fileSystems':true,'formData':true,'history':true,'indexedDB':true,'localStorage':true,'serverBoundCertificates':true,'passwords':true,'pluginData':true,'serviceWorkers':true,'webSQL':true});
}

init();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`chrome.runtime.onStartup` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup).

When you update / manually reload an extension, its `onInstalled` event triggers, but not `onStartup`. On the other hand, on every browser start you get `onStartup` event.

```
// background script
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  // Nuke things here, probably with chrome.browsingData API
});
```

Note that in case Chrome continues to run in the background when the last window is closed (e.g. a Chrome App is still running, or some extension requested the `"background"` permission), re-opening that window won't register as `onStartup`. A workaround is to use `chrome.windows.onCreated` to see if the newly opened window is the only one:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
  chrome.windows.getAll(function(windows) {
    if (windows.length == 1) {
      // Chrome was running, but in background: it now "opened"
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: That's not a helpful description of why it's not what you want.

Comment: Well, now that you edited your question, I don't understand why my solution doesn't work for you.